# Optimization function convex or not

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, matlab

I need to comment whether my optimization function is convex or non-convex. My optimization function is in the form of $(y-y_{cap})^2$.  y  is know. $y_{cap}$ comes out of a MATLAB pfile. So,  $y_{cap}$ can be considered output of a black-box model. It is also not possible to plot $y-y_{cap}$ as it is a $22\times8$ matrix. Please help me to comment whether the optimization function is convex or non-convex,

Comment: y-ycap is a matrix of size 22*8, i mass it as a column matrix to lsqnonlin and minimize it. y is known, y_cap comes out of a black box. I need to comment if (y-ycap) is convex or not?

Comment: Yes, it is convex function!

Comment: How do you say it is convex? y_cap = B(x) where B is a black box.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a black-box model, which takes some inputs $x$ and map them to $y_{cap}$. Lets call this model $B$, so we have $y_{cap} = B(x)$. Then, your objective is $$\|y - B(x)\|^2.$$
This is *not* convex, unless $B$ is actually an affine function.

Comment: As as you said y_cap = B(x). I am not sure how we can comment whether B is affine or not, as B is a black box. So how do you conclude its not convex?

Comment: @gerw I think that the question considers the cost function that depends only on $y_{cap}$. Now, $y_{cap}$ is expressed from the other variable. I have no comment for this situation :v

Comment: @HarishSatyavada: If you do not know what $B$ is, we can say nothing, but most likely your function won't be convex.

Comment: Yes most likelyit is not convex, if i solve it using MATLAB command $lsqnonlin$ and get mutiple minima then can we conclude it is not convex? I think lsqnonlin returns local minimas right?

Comment: @Mr.VN  . I have to optimise paramters "(theta)" of a model of a railway network "F". This railway model is given to me in the form of a MATLAB-p file, so it is a black box. I have been given two data sets from the model, input u and output y. The output of my railway model "F" is say y_cap.

Then y_cap = F(u,theta). 

I take my optimisation function so as to minimise square of error between y and y_cap that is (y-y_cap)^2 and tune the parameters theta. That is objective function = (y-y_cap)^2.  Is my objective function convex or not?

Comment: @gerw I have to optimise paramters "(theta)" of a model of a railway network "F". This railway model is given to me in the form of a MATLAB-p file, so it is a black box. I have been given two data sets from the model, input u and output y. The output of my railway model "F" is say y_cap. Then y_cap = F(u,theta). I take my optimisation function so as to minimise square of error between y and y_cap that is (y-y_cap)^2 and tune the parameters theta. That is objective function = (y-y_cap)^2. Is my objective function convex or not?

Comment: @HarishSatyavada If you can find solution (even multiple solutions), it is embarrassed to say that the function is not convex since it can be local solution or the function is quasi-convex. I think that you are confusing what should be optimized parameters.  I guess the cost function might be $\mathcal{G}(\theta) = (y - f(\theta))^2$ rather than $\mathcal{G}(y_{cap}) = (y - y_{cap})^2$.

Comment: @Mr.VN yes the function is $G(\theta)$= (y-f(\theta))^2, so how do you conclude its not convex? f is the black-box. And yes, using $lsqnonlin$ with different starting points, I end up with same cost function, but different theta values. So is it non convex? And is there any theoritical way of proving it?